# PayPal Pro setup Error 10548

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro

while paypal test checkout. I got an error mentioned below.

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2017-09-22T09:01:00Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 8d454e5592202
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 65.1
[BUILD] => 36082234
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10548
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[AMT] => 10.00
[CURRENCYCODE] => USD
```

I has checked for all stack answers and youtube tutorials. 
    I has created  sandbox business account for us country,  added balance, upgraded to pro,  on modal in settings tab: PayPal Credit- on, login with pal - all these steps are done. copy the credential under api tab and pasted them to code you provide.

```
But while make payments. I got the above mentioned errors. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!
```

Answer (score 2):

Your account where it calls the API should be upgrade to PRO before you make the DoDirectPayment API.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs if you don't have a business account. You must have a business PayPal account within a PayPal Payments Pro-enabled country to use the Direct Payment API. The absence of a home or customer service phone number on your PayPal account can also trigger this error.

**Solution**

If you have a business account and you get this error, check your PayPal account profile and make sure it includes a home phone number or a customer service phone number. Update your profile if necessary.

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1147&actp=LIST